# Sort 2 dimensional array based on the distance to its average

Tags: python, arrays, sorting, mean, closest

How can I sort a 2d numpy array based on the closest rows members to the array average.

For example, we have this array:

```
a = np.random.rand(10,4)
```

its mean can be given like:

```
myAverage = a.mean(axis=0)
```

Now, I want to sort a based on the closest distance to myAverage

Thank you

This is what I have tried:

```py
for i in range(a.shape[0]):
    for j in range(a.shape[0] - 1):
        if(abs(sum(a[i] - a[i].mean(axis=0) > a[j + 1] - a[j +1].mean(axis=0)))):
            a[i] = a[j]
```

Comment: Do you want to sort columns or rows?

Comment: Best thing you can do here is provide an example

Comment: @DanielMesejo rows and I just edited the question. Thanks

Comment: But I believe you are computing the average of the columns?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assume you mean the absolute distance, otherwise take out the `np.abs()`:

```
import numpy as np

np.random.seed(0)
a = np.random.rand(10,4)



row_means = np.mean(a,axis=1,keepdims=True)

row_means_dist = a - row_means


sorted_idx = np.argsort(np.abs(row_means_dist).min(axis=1))

result = a[sorted_idx]
```

Comment: Thanks, I actually want result to return the original array values not the distance
Can you please show how to do that?

Comment: This exactly what I wanted. Thank you!

Comment: No problem! Please accept it if you think it is the correct answer =)

Answer (score 1):

This may not be the most efficient solution, but you could convert the numpy array representing each row to a python list:

```
    row_array = list(a[row_num])
```

and sort using:

```
    sorted(row_array, key=lambda x: abs(x - myAverage[row_num]))
```

and convert back to a numpy array.

```
    a[row_num] = np.toarray(row_array)
```